# How do I change the start menu icon on Zorin OS?

Tags: theme, zorin

I changed the start-here.png and the gnome-main-menu.png for all sizes in the Zorin theme. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://zoringroup.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=3 is the support forum for ZorisOS. I'd suggest signing in there and searching for the location of the start menu icon.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. For anyone wondering how, you go to `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/zorin-app-grid@zorinos.com` and change `zorin-icon-symbolic.svg` to your image

Answer (score 0):

İcon Dir: `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/symbolic/apps/`

first convert your logo png to svg file.

Use it: https://onlineconvertfree.com/tr/convert-format/png-to-svg/

And rename: "xfce4-zorinmenulite-symbolic.svg"

Movie icon dir.

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam.
Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.